# QGIS polygonize issue: GDAL DLL load failed

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I am using QGIS Desktop 3.10.0 and I have some issues with the polygonize tool. When I run the polygonize tool, a warning shows up saying that there is an “Import Error: DLL load failed” (see Figure 2). I also tried to use this tool in QGIS 3.4 (stable version), but it also did not work. How can I fix this issue, please?

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: it works for me, so I think, something is wrong with you install. Installing different versions share certain dll's, so it is not suprising, that both fail. How did you install qgis? Did you get any errors during install?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. It's probably related to your GDAL version. With QGIS 3.10, some algorithms require GDAL 3.1, which is a higher version of GDAL than is currently distributed with QGIS. To confirm this in QGIS, go to View > Panels > Log Messages. If the GDAL version is the problem, you will see a message similar to this: "The 'GDAL==3.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application."

As a possible work around, if you copy the console line call from 'gdal_polygonize' to the end, you can paste and run it in the console to get the desired output with your current GDAL version.

Comment: You can also try consulting the gdal version directly in the Python console, just type in the command line:

import osgeo.gdal
osgeo.gdal.__version__

Answer (score 0):

Could also be related to the fact that there are two QGIS executables that get installed, one without a lot of the additional extensions, one with.
Check your shortcuts folder, there should be two icons/executables.
Make sure you run 'QGIS Desktop with Grass 7.x'.exe